# Are there any way to restore closed tabs in okular pdf viewer?

Tags: pdf, zathura, okular, bspwm

I am on an Arch Linux machine and okular is probably the best pdf viewer, except just one lacking feature which is restoring tabs when you reopen Okular. Now since there is no default option for doing it, and while I can always make a feature request,  I was hoping for some easy out of the box solution, if there is any. I am using bspwm window manager.

If there is some window manager route then probably the same can be done for zathura too. I think zathura doesn't have a restore tab option either since it doesn't have a tab option. I am using zathura tabs through [tabc](https://www.reddit.com/r/bspwm/comments/pfajrd/bsptab_tabs_in_bspwm_with_tabbed/).

Comment: What do you mean ? Looking for something more immediate than File > Open Recent ?

Comment: @MC68020 Yes like we have an option in firefox or qpdf-view that enables automatically starting from previous state from where we closed. But in Okular I think there is no suck option. In firefox there is an inbuilt shortcut `ctrl+shift+t` that opens the last closed tab. Even a shortcut like that can help. But a way to automatically restoring the previous state would be best.